# In REST Assured, how do I set a timeout?

Tags: java-8, httpclient, rest-assured

I'm using RestAssured 2.8.0 
and I'm trying to set my own timeout (for gateway timeout),
so if I don't get response after X milliseconds I want to abort.

I tried:

```
public static ValidatableResponse postWithConnectionConfig(String url, String body, RequestSpecification requestSpecification, ResponseSpecification responseSpecification) {
    ConnectionConfig.CloseIdleConnectionConfig closeIdleConnectionConfig = new ConnectionConfig.CloseIdleConnectionConfig(1L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    ConnectionConfig connectionConfig = new ConnectionConfig(closeIdleConnectionConfig);
    RestAssuredConfig restAssuredConfig = new RestAssuredConfig().connectionConfig(connectionConfig);


    return given().specification(requestSpecification)
            .body(body)
            .config(restAssuredConfig)
            .post(url)
            .then()
            .specification(responseSpecification);

}
```

or

```
ConnectionConfig connectionConfig = new ConnectionConfig()
            .closeIdleConnectionsAfterEachResponseAfter(10L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
RestAssuredConfig restAssuredConfig = new RestAssuredConfig().connectionConfig(connectionConfig);
```

I also tried to add

```
.queryParam("SO_TIMEOUT", 10)
```

or

```
.queryParam("CONNECTION_MANAGER_TIMEOUT", 10)
```

nothing seem to work.
It doesn't abort my query

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can configure timeouts by setting HTTP client parameters:

```
RestAssuredConfig config = RestAssured.config()
        .httpClient(HttpClientConfig.httpClientConfig()
                .setParam(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, 1000)
                .setParam(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, 1000));

given().config(config).post("http://localhost:8884");
```

Comment: The CoreConnectionPNames seems to be deprecated. Is there a new way to configure the timeouts ?

Comment: See https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/935 and https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/497

Answer (score 11):

Since `CoreConnectionPNames` is deprecated here's a newer way. This works for Apache HTTP client 4.5.3:

```
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;

import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.config.HttpClientConfig;
```

...

```
RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
    .setConnectTimeout(5000)
    .setConnectionRequestTimeout(5000)
    .setSocketTimeout(5000)
    .build();

HttpClientConfig httpClientFactory = HttpClientConfig.httpClientConfig()
    .httpClientFactory(() -> HttpClientBuilder.create()
        .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
        .build());

RestAssured.config = RestAssured
    .config()
    .httpClient(httpClientFactory);
```

Comment: You should get a `ClassCastException` this way as discussed [here](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/497).

Restassured doesn't support uses of external httpClient. You currently have to produce an `AbstractHttpClient`

Comment: any fix on that :? with the ClassCastException ?

Comment: Documented here https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#http-client-config

Comment: @arulraj.net As far as I can see there is no fix for that. The only option is to continue to use the deprecated classes. See https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/497 Or do you see any other alternative?

Answer (score 8):

Following configuration worked for me.

```
RestAssured.config=RestAssuredConfig.config()
                        .httpClient(HttpClientConfig.httpClientConfig()
                                .setParam("http.socket.timeout",1000)
                                .setParam("http.connection.timeout", 1000));
```