# I need to keep the test alive for min 30 minutes without time out

Tags: api, rest-assured, web-api-testing

I have a test scenario where I need to upload a large file via api, and it approximately takes 30minutes, how can I keep the test alive and wait till the response is thrown back ?Currently i added some waits but I am sure expectedConditions / waits are not going to help me. Any other suggestions or anyone had similar experiences?

Currently i added some waits but I am sure expectedConditions / waits are not going to help me. Any other suggestions or anyone had similar experiences?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In REST Assured, how do I set a timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46889970/in-rest-assured-how-do-i-set-a-timeout)

Comment: @bhusak no,I need to keep it alive for minimum 30minutes, i dont think link helps me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide too many details in your question, but I think using [Awaitility](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility) may help you solve the problem.

If not, try to provide more details on what you want to achieve and what did you try so far.